# Why is it possible for the dot operator (.) to be used with private class members/methods?

Tags: c++, operators

A bit of an idiotic question but this has suddenly popped up into my mind:

Why is it possible for the dot operator to be utilized with private members of an object (within a member/friend function)? I admit I've been using it for some time now, but I had never thought of it until now. But considering it is used for public member functions, it seems a bit weird.

Can anyone provide some insight?

For example (edit: I'm learning about overloaded operators in class):

```
rational rational::operator/(const rational &obj2) const
{
    rational value;
    value.num = (*this).num * obj2.denom;
    value.denom = (*this).denom * obj2.num;
    return value;
}
```

Thank you all who've answered! :)

Comment: Why would there need to be a different operator?

Comment: Learning about overloaded operators in class.

Comment: How else would your `operator/` access the members of `obj2`?

Comment: There would be no other way - I knew I could use the dot operator in that case, but I wondered why and how it was possible to use it when it was limited to only public members of a class object (which is untrue, which I've since learned)

Comment: But you never learned otherwise. Operators don't depend on access control. You've just made up an arbitrary rule and asked why it doesn't apply. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: It was taught to me by both my professor and through my C++ textbook, which is why I was confused and thus asked this question. I didn't exactly make it up; please keep your assumptions to yourself.

Comment: No offense that is, sorry about that. Just got somewhat heated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.` is for member access in general (methods or variables), irrespective of the visibility. This was simply a language design choice. Generally, one tries to avoid adding more syntax than necessary, and "`a.b` means that we're accessing the member `b` of `a`" is a nice and simple rule - which is better than having to learn e.g. "`a.b` is for accessing a public method, `a#b` is for accessing a private method, `a@b` is for accessing a public field, ...".

Note, though, that using `.` to access a private member from outside of the class' own code is a compilation error (except if you're doing it from a class or method that is declared to be a friend of the member's class). Most of a language's syntax has rules specifying in which contexts the syntax may be used.

Comment: Friends also have access to private members.